# How to set any polygon the same total width

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I can't figure out how to set any polygon (for example a triangle, decagon, square etc) the same 'total width' in python turtle.
I have 2 definitions:

```
# To draw the shape
def shape(sides):
    for i in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(20);
        turtle.right(360 / sides);

# To move to the next shape
def nextshape():
    turtle.penup();
    turtle.forward(50);
    turtle.pendown();
```

The problem is is that the difference between different shapes varies, depending on how many sides there are.
For example, if I wanted to draw a shape with 4 sides (a square) its 'total width' (I would say diameter but I think that is for circles) would be 20, because it is drawing each side a width of 20. However, if I draw a shape with 5 sides, its 'total width' would not be 20 because of its amount of sides, which causes the shape to go outwards when drawing it.
What I want is the 'total width' of any shape with any amount of sides to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is "perimeter". If I understand right, you're attempting to draw an arbitrary n-sided polygon (triangle when n=3, square when n=4, etc.) with a constant perimeter size.
The perimeter of an n-sided polygon is `n * length_of_side`.

Since you want the perimeter of all polygons to be the same, what you need to be calculating is `length_of_side`, which is simply `perimeter / n`

```
PERIMETER = 20

def shape(sides):
    for i in range(sides):
        length_of_side = PERIMETER / sides
        turtle.forward(length_of_side);
        turtle.right(360 / sides);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your concept of "total width" is flawed.  If we consider the square of sides 20, and think of "total width" as "maximum width" then the corner points furthest apart on the perimeter are roughly 28 pixels apart (20 * sqrt(2)).  This concept of "maximum width", makes sense for polygons, unlike "total width".  And it's analogous to "diameter" which you mentioned.

Here's code to draw polygons of varying numbers of side with a constant diameter:

```
import turtle

DIAMETER = 200

def shape(sides):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(-DIAMETER/2)  # center polygon on turtle position
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.circle(DIAMETER/2, steps=sides)

for sides in range(3, 13):
    shape(sides)

turtle.done()
```

The main point being, you need to define your goal clearly.

Answer (score -1):

You should start with 1 polygon so (this is a triangle)

sides=3

def shape(sides):
for i in range(sides):
turtle.forward(how long the side is)
turtle.right(360/sides)

And run the program:

shape(sides)